# Existence of infinite product measure (part of proof)

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, measure-theory

Currently I am taking a lecture which is based on the book 'Probability with Martingales' by David Williams. So far we are on the topic of infinite product measures and I'm struggling with the proof of the following lemma which belongs to the existence of such an infinite product measure:

> Let $\Omega $ be the set of all real-valued sequences and $\mathcal{A}_k $ the $\sigma$-Algebra generated by the sets $\{(\omega_n):\omega_1 \in B_1,\dots,\omega_k \in B_k\} $, with $B_1,\dots,B_k\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Elements of $\mathcal{A_k}$ can be written as $$ A_k=\{(\omega_n):(\omega_1,\dots,\omega_k)\in B_k\} \text{ for } B_k \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R^k}).$$
>   Let $\mathcal{A}_0$ be the algebra defined as $$\mathcal{A}_0 := \bigcup_{1 \leq \ell \leq k} \mathcal{A}_\ell$$ and define $P_0:\mathcal{A}_0 \rightarrow [0,1] $ as 
>   $$ P_0(\{(\omega_n):(\omega_1,\dots,\omega_k) \in B_k \})=P_1 (B_1)\otimes\dots\otimes P_k(B_k).$$
>
> **Show:** If $(H_n)$ is a falling sequence of sets in $\mathcal{A}_0$ and $\epsilon>0$ exists so that $P_0(H_n)\geq \epsilon$ for all $n$, then $\cap_n H_n \neq \emptyset.$

Although I have seen that a proof is given on p.229 in 'Probability with Martingales', I am still confused because it includes topics my professor did not talk about yet and also because the whole notation of it is overwhelming me a bit.

Comment: It seems like your notation is a bit problematic (also, as far as I can see, is not the one employed in Williams' book). For example, you introduce $\mathcal{A}_0$, but actually you start to count from $1$ up to $k$.

Comment: I used the same notation as my professor in his lecture. He used specifically $\mathcal{A_0}$, cause all the other natural numbers were already taken. But I noticed that I missed something in the definition, $\mathcal{A}_0 := \cup_k \mathcal{A}_k$. I edited in my original post, thanks for the hint.

Comment: Ok. Mind another thing about this notation: is $$\mathcal{A}_0 := \bigcup_{1 \leq \ell \leq k} A_\ell$$ or $$\mathcal{A}_0 := \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} A_k?$$

Comment: The first one. It should be the union of all generated $\sigma$-algebras from 1 to k.

Comment: I edited accordingly (and I also corrected some minor typos), but are you sure? It looks a weird notational choice, since we end up having countably many $\mathcal{A}_0$ for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$. It would better to have a notational device that tells us for which $k \in \mathbb{N}$ we are actually constructing $\mathcal{A}_0$, i.e., something like $\mathcal{A}^{k}_0$. *(Mind that I am asking you all those questions since you pointed out that you found the notation a bit overwhelming, thus this process could help in disentangling it.)*